# how could create image watermark using ImageMagick

Tags: image, bitmap, imagemagick, gif, watermark

I am trying to convert a 8bpp (256) color gif to a 2bpp (4) color gif through ImageMagick.

How can i put an semi-transparent image to the output file in ImageMagick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ImageMagick's `composite` command.

Here are a couple links to tutorials and examples of using ImageMagick to add watermarks to your pictures:

- [from the ImageMagick help files](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#watermarking)
- [a blog example](http://joakim.erdfelt.com/wiki/index.php/AddingWatermarksWithImageMagick)
- [yet another blog example](http://www.waltercedric.com/joomla-mainmenu-247/303-how-to/1668-watermarking-your-images-with-imagemagick.html)